# PHP script to send email invitations to join a site

Tags: php, email, invitation

Are there any popular scripts to send invitations to join a website, to user's address book contacts? When he enters email ID and password, it should grab all contacts and email each one using swiftmailer. I only need the grabbing part :)
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to use the API offered by some mail services to retrieve contact information. This is specific per email service. Google, Yahoo and most of the other email providers offer their own set of API that is what you want to use.

In [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326379/php-apis-for-hotmail-gmail-and-yahoo) are contained information on how to use these API from PHP.

Comment: Are there any free scripts/ tutorials that i can follow?

Thanks