# Retrieve contact list from Hotmail using PHP/CURL

Tags: php, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP APIs for Hotmail, Gmail and Yahoo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326379/php-apis-for-hotmail-gmail-and-yahoo)

hi guys
how is it possible to login hotmail through curl-php for obtaining the contact list?
pleaze show me an example code

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326379/php-apis-for-hotmail-gmail-and-yahoo

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://openinviter.com/