# Get GMail, Yahoo, Hotmail, etc. contacts

Tags: php, jquery, web-services, api

I'm building a web application wherein I want my users to be able to invite their email and FB contacts to checkout my web app. Is there a plugin, library, or web service I can use to make this easy for all?

I'm using PHP, jQuery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP APIs for Hotmail, Gmail and Yahoo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326379/php-apis-for-hotmail-gmail-and-yahoo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at http://openinviter.com/ or http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/

Comment: socialauth is good ... however, not specific to PHP which is what he was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

As @Du3 mentioned ... socialauth is good, however, you requested PHP support:

- http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/

This is fundamentally how you would consume services by the other providers.  Searching on stackoverflow also gives some good answers:

- [PHP APIs for Hotmail, Gmail and Yahoo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326379/php-apis-for-hotmail-gmail-and-yahoo)