# Get contact list from gmail, yahoo, hotmail

Tags: api, gmail, contacts

I wish to write an `API` that can get the contacts list from Gmail, Yahoo and other e-mails. How can this be done? Are there already existing `APIs` for them or do I need to write `PHP` code to extract information?

I need a referral system like DropBox has. Has anyone coded it themselves or is it available as open source?

https://www.dropbox.com/referrals

Please guide me in this regard. Any link or explanation will do the job.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google has an API: http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/contacts/
And Yahoo also has an API: http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/

There exists some other which are mentioned in this thread: [PHP APIs for Hotmail, Gmail and Yahoo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326379/php-apis-for-hotmail-gmail-and-yahoo)

Answer (score -7):

simple 5 step to get contact list from gmail
1. open gmail account
2. click gmail dropdown
3. click  on Contacts
4. Click on More dropdown button
5. Now click on Export...  , and download email db

http://all-easy-tricks.blogspot.in/p/how-to-get-gmailemail-id-contacts-list.html

[click here](http://all-easy-tricks.blogspot.in/p/how-to-get-gmailemail-id-contacts-list.html)

Comment: he is asking for api approach