# Import contact list from, Hotmail, Yahoo, LinkedIn, MySpace API'S in iphone SDK

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios5, linkedin-api, myspace

Can any one help how to import contact list from Hotmail,Yahoo, LinkedIn, and Myspace API's.

I have googling since last two days but no luck.

I have found some discussions on net but it will be not useful for me.

http://www.linkedin.com/answers/using-linkedIn/ULI/702062-20578814
http://www.linkedin.com/answers/marketing-sales/sales/customer-relationship-management/MAR_SLS_CRM/645042-9410989

http://www.linkedin.com/answers/using-linkedIn/ULI/929807-1834502

Can anyone gives any idea in this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/326664/581190 https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api http://developer.myspace.com/community/forums/p/1380/52263.aspx

Answer (score 3):

**Yahoo**

Here is the Yahoo Contacts API: http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/

You would call into their REST API, and provide a YQL Query. It returns JSON. A JSON library is built into the latest iOS SDK.

**LinkedIn**

Similarly, LinkedIn has: developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-api-resource-map

The LinkedIn API seems to be returning XML, so you'll need an XML parsing library.

This is a great description and comparison of various available XML parsing libraries:  raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project . If you're not sure, go with a DOM parser -- it is more intuitive to me at least. I hope you remember how to traverse trees.

**Hotmail, MySpace, others**

Look for REST APIs -- these are generic web based APIs that will work with any client. You can do server-to-server communication, as well as client-server communication (both in-browser (JS) and native apps).

**Now that you have this data in memory**

You can iterate through it, and add contacts to your iOS device using the Address Book API: 
developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html

By the way, what's MySpace?